# VBA ServerXMLHTTP code works in Windows 7 but fails in Windows 10

Tags: vba, windows-10, serverxmlhttp

Using VBA in Microsoft Access, I am sending XML to a server to get a response string.  It works fine in Windows 7.  Recently, some users have upgraded to Windows 10, and this no longers works (all users on Office 16).  The specific error is:
-2147012867 - A connection with the server could not be established.

The error occurs on the xsite.send line

Here is the code:

```
Dim xsite As ServerXMLHTTP60
Set xsite = New ServerXMLHTTP60

On Error Resume Next

xsite.setTimeouts 0, 60000, 30000, 600000

xsite.Open "POST", pServerURL & func, False
aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)
On Error GoTo 0
If 0 = aErr(0) Then 'No error creating the link
    xsite.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    'Set request header with Base64-encoded username/password
    xsite.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64(UserName & ":" & Password)
    On Error Resume Next
    xsite.send "xmlData=" & URLEncode(xmldata)
    aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Debug.Print aErr(0)
    Debug.Print aErr(1)
End If
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem may be in your `EncodeBase64` function?  Or your `URLEncode` function ?  Ore you have a different firewall on your Win10 boxes.

Comment: test on win10 using the actual string that is returned by the encodeBase64 function

Comment: Set all timeouts the same, and check if there is a timeout delay before error occurs? Try `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` and `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`, also try to change URL and to remove headers - just to see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Haven't tested your code but it appears similar to mine, it also works in Windows7 but not on Windows10. I found out that it was  the Windows10 firewall who blocked it. Yours probably works if you turn off the firewall. I tried different approaches to make an exception to my firewall but never succeded. So the few times I have to run my code I have to shut the firewall down.